# unix: count number of jpeg files recursively except for one subfolder in every folder?

Tags: unix, recursion, count

I think the code to count all the jpeg files recursively in a folder is,

```
find . -type f -name "*.jpeg" | wc -l
```

but I now realize I need to exclude some subfolders...

for instance, my folder consists of 5 subfolders and in each subfolder there is a subsubfolder named "meh" consisting of jpeg files I wish not to include in my count... Could anyone let me know how to do that?

Thanks so much for your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with find's [option](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) `-prune` or `-regex`.

```
find . -name meh -prune -o -name '*.jpeg' -print | wc -l
find . -not -regex '.*/meh/.*' -a -name '*.jpeg' -print | wc -l
```

Weird that @Prune didn't answer that.

Answer (score 0):

Since find includes the relative path of each file, you could do this:

```
find . -type f -name "*.jpeg" | grep -vc /meh/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use any **grep** variant to filter the output of find.
While you're doing that, use the *count* option from grep, *-c*.
*-v* is reverse logic: list only those that do *not* match the given pattern.

```
find . -type f -name "*.jpeg" | egrep -c -v "/meh/"
```